# Implement reciprocal of a floating point number using Chebyshev approximation in CKKS

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am trying to obtain the reciprocal of a floating point value $x$ using the Chebyshev approximation, where $x$ is mostly in the order of $10^3$ to $10^5$. Subsequently, I am trying to implement that algorithm using CKKS for secure computation. My initial attempt with Taylor's series didn't help me that much due to accuracy issues; hence I am looking for alternate solutions. I am trying to obtain an algorithm based on Chebyshev approximation to achieve the same.

I found a plaintext implementation in this link: https://github.com/usnistgov/ChebTools. However, as per the unit testing, the reciprocal test case fails. Simunatnesouly, some computations are not possible to implement using CKKS. I also found an openFHE library here: https://github.com/openfheorg/openfhe-development/tree/main. I believe this library contains an implementation of division using Chebyshev interpolation. However, I could not find the algorithm from this library. It will be really helpful if a division algorithm using Chebyshev approximation can be found. Your help in this regard is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Chebyshev approximation was initially used to homomorphically compute $x\mapsto \sin(x)$ (which itself was a stand-in for $x\mapsto \lfloor x\rfloor$), see for example [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/1043.pdf). In general division for CKKS is quite hard.
I have seen people suggest that the most reasonable things to do are to use [division algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Fast_division_methods) for it.
For example, [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/417.pdf) uses Goldschmidt's division algorithm to compute $f(x) = 1/x$.

That being said, [further work](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1234) dropped Goldschmidt's algorithm, and instead used techniques that appear to avoid computing $x\mapsto 1/x$.
You can argue these further techniques do actually still compute this function (using Goldschmidt's algorithm), but this is something I haven't written up/published, so is perhaps difficult to communicate in a crypto.stackexchange answer box.
The short answer is that (part of) the above work can be seen as

1. taking a Pade approximant to $f(x) = \mathsf{sign}(x)$, meaning an approximation of this function by a quotient of two polynomials $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, and then
2. approximating $q(x)\mapsto 1/q(x)$ using Goldschmidt.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for your answer. I didn't understand the first point of your proposed solution. Can you please elaborate a little bit more about that or provide me with some materials that can help?

Comment: Maybe this is more useful --- [here](https://github.com/openfheorg/openfhe-development/blob/main/src/pke/examples/function-evaluation.cpp) (say line 161) is an example of how to evaluate $\sqrt{x}$ in OpenFHE using Chebyshev approximation. The adaptation to $x\mapsto 1/x$ should be immediate.